# How to retrain a custom spacy model?

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am creating a custom model for detecting usernames and emails and other lables. I have generated a set of 10000 sentences (json), and converted it to spacy, and a list of users, emails.
I am using command `spacy train` to create the model.
After testing I have found few cases (let say 100 new sentences) which are not working.  How do I train the model again with only extra sentences??